# Any script/stylesheet compressors for ASP.NET without MVC or something similar?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, css, yslow

I am trying to find a nice solution to concatenate and compress javascript and css in my webpage to improve YSlow performance.  The website is built using ASP.NET in both VB and C#.  I seen some cool tools, like Cassette and Chirpy, but they both seem to need some aspect of the MVC framework that I don't have.  Any ideas?

So far the best I've found is a version of Chirpy that will do compression and whatnot inside visual studio, which is cool, but not as automated as I would like.

Comment: Are you trying to do this at runtime, or is a build tool fine (such as MSBuild plugin)?

Comment: trying to do it runtime, but caching to a local file.  i guess either way, as long as they aren't compiled on the fly every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SquishIt](http://www.codethinked.com/squishit-the-friendly-aspnet-javascript-and-css-squisher) is fairly useful and simple to setup.

It uses YUI Compressor and can minify CSS/Javascript.

Comment: this is what I am looking for, thanks.  I still have some questions about how it works, but so far it functions very similar to Cassette, but fits into my VB project better.

Answer (score 0):

I use [YUI Compressor.](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/)  Its nice because every time you build your project it will automatically minify it for you.  Lots of good tutorials out there for it as well.  I used this page to figure out how to configure my .xml file.  [Link](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Sample%20MSBuild.xml%20File&ProjectName=yuicompressor)

Answer (score 0):

We used [FrogMSBuild](http://www.nhanminh.com/en-us/blog.aspx/entries/automatically-combine-files-in-visual-studio.aspx) to combine files and [MS Ajax Minifier](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/40584) to minify the resulting files. See my [short summary](http://devio.wordpress.com/2011/03/01/merge-and-minify-as-visual-studio-build-tasks/) on how to set them up in a web project.

Answer (score 0):

Check if Microsoft Ajax Minifier would fit your needs. Do you need a dynamic/runtime or static/compile time minifier?

Here is the snippet from the project build file.

```
  <!-- Ajax Minifier -->
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\MicrosoftAjax\ajaxmin.tasks" />
  <Target Name="AfterBuild" Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <ItemGroup>
      <JS Include="**\*.js" Exclude="**\extJS\**;**\extJS_extensions\**" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <AjaxMin JsSourceFiles="@(JS)" JsSourceExtensionPattern="\.js$" JsTargetExtension=".js" />
  </Target>
```